# How to read and extract a attribute data from HE5 (HDF5) dataset in R

Tags: r, raster, hdf5, rgdal, rhdf5

The dataset contains following groups with different attribute data. How can i extract and plot the attribute number 8 with latitude longitude using the packages 'rhdf5','rgdal' and 'raster'?

```
8  /HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields              ColumnAmountNO2Trop H5I_DATASET  FLOAT 1440 x 720
```

```
h5ls("D:/NO2/NO2 Data/2008/1Jan/OMI-Aura_L3-OMNO2d_2008m0101_v003-2018m0626t175046.he5")

                                       group                             name       otype dclass        dim
0                                          /                           HDFEOS   H5I_GROUP                  
1                                    /HDFEOS                       ADDITIONAL   H5I_GROUP                  
2                         /HDFEOS/ADDITIONAL                  FILE_ATTRIBUTES   H5I_GROUP                  
3                                    /HDFEOS                            GRIDS   H5I_GROUP                  
4                              /HDFEOS/GRIDS                  ColumnAmountNO2   H5I_GROUP                  
5              /HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2                      Data Fields   H5I_GROUP                  
6  /HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields                  ColumnAmountNO2 H5I_DATASET  FLOAT 1440 x 720
7  /HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields     ColumnAmountNO2CloudScreened H5I_DATASET  FLOAT 1440 x 720
8  /HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields              ColumnAmountNO2Trop H5I_DATASET  FLOAT 1440 x 720
9  /HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields ColumnAmountNO2TropCloudScreened H5I_DATASET  FLOAT 1440 x 720
10 /HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields                           Weight H5I_DATASET  FLOAT 1440 x 720
11                                         /               HDFEOS INFORMATION   H5I_GROUP                  
12                       /HDFEOS INFORMATION                 StructMetadata.0 H5I_DATASET STRING      ( 0 )
```

I used the following command to read the attribute within a group but it shows error

```
E = h5read("D:/NO2/NO2 Data/2008/1Jan/OMI-Aura_L3-OMNO2d_2008m0101_v003-2018m0626t175046.he5","HDFEOS/GRIDS/ColumnAmountNO2/Data Fields/ColumnAmountNO2Trop")
Warning message:
In h5checktypeOrOpenLoc(file, readonly = TRUE, native = native) :
  An open HDF5 file handle exists. If the file has changed on disk meanwhile, the function may not work properly. Run 'h5closeAll()' to close all open HDF5 object handles.
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running h5closeAll() as the error message suggests? If yes, you may also want to try removing the group info from your command, i.e. E = h5read("D:/NO2/NO2 Data/2008/1Jan/OMI-Aura_L3-OMNO2d_2008m0101_v003-2018m0626t175046.he5","ColumnAmountNO2Trop")

Comment: h5closeAll() does it !! Thanks. There is another problem now to plot the attribute data with latitude and longitude. It does not have spatial reference. How do i do it? Dim(var) gives me 1440  720